# SwiftUI 2.0 prevent static image reload at each body refresh

Tags: swiftui

Is there anyway to prevent below image to be downloaded each time the button updates the qty?

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var qty:Int = 0
    var imageUrl:String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Button(action:{self.qty += 1})
            URLImage(ImageLoader(), self.imageUrl)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `URLImage` and `ImageLoader`? I assume `URLImage` is the view and does the "work". Tell us what they are doing, and show the code. Depending how this code works: You may want to instead get/create the image in the init as `UIImage`, and then use `Image(uiImage: myImage)`.

Comment: Well, I didn't add them for simplicity; ImageLoader is a helper which asynchronously downloads an image and displays it on URLImage View

Comment: I assumed `URLImage` might be the one loading the image, because you give it the `imageUrl`. So you are asynchronously loading an image with `ImageLoader()`... how? You can't asynchronously load an image and pass in the returned result. You should show more code. The aim here is to load the image in the `init`, `.onAppear`, or similar. Save that to a property in `TestView`, then display that image. It will then only be downloaded once.

Comment: each time qty changes a brand new `URLImage` gets created with brand new `ImageLoader`. Is Image Loader an `ObservableObject`, does it hold on to the dowloaded image?

Comment: You are right @LuLuGaGa, I finally made ImageLoader an ObservedObject on TestView() and ask it if the image had been loaded in order to display either the image or a loading indicator. Since the image is a property of ImageLoader ObservedObject it gets now loaded just once.

Comment: Good to hear it works!